# I am learning jquery, I am practicing and stuck to get selected option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a onchange property on select element and I want to get the value of selected option in another function how can i get it?
Thank in advance.
Here is my html

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" onChange="stateChange(this.value)">
         <option>SELECT COUNTRY</option>
          //all countries name like bellow
          <option value="USA"> USA </option>
................
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="city" id="state">
      <option>SELECT CITY</option>
         </select>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group btn-field">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="submit" id="create-account" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="CREATE ACCOUNT">
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

stateChange work perfectly but when I want to get this in bellow function it always return option 1 here #create-account is a button's id

```
$('#create-account').click(function (e) {

            var country = $('#country option:selected').text();
            alert(country);

        });



var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania",........);

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2]="Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
.........
function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );

    stateElement.length=0;  // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function stateChange(country) {
    for(var pos=0;pos<=country_arr.length;pos++)
    {
        if (country==country_arr[pos])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    ++pos;
    if(pos<253)
    {
        populateState(pos);
    }

}
function populateState(countryId)
{
    var state_arr = s_a[countryId].split("|");

    var select = document.getElementById('state');

    for(var s = select.options.length - 1 ; s >= 0 ; s--)
    {
        select.remove(s);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i<state_arr.length; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = state_arr[i];
        opt.innerHTML = state_arr[i];
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a button with `create-account` id and it will work fine.

Comment: already did that. just skipped it in descripion

Comment: Then what's the problem? It works just fine, except the fact that you didn't provide the `stateChange` function.

Comment: yeap even here another selecting works fine var city = $('#state option:selected').text();

Comment: You're not showing what stateChange function is doing, which may well be what causes the trouble...

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit : The problem was that your country variable is defined within you click function. It doesnt exist out of that. So what you have to do is declare the country variable at the top of your javascript code in the global scope like so

```
        var country="";

        $('#create-account').click(function (e) {
        country = $('#country option:selected').text();
        alert(country);

        });
```

Is this what you want? for the value to show up instead of the text? In that case you just have to get the select tag and run it with .val() to get the value

```js
$('#create-account').click(function (e) {

            var country = $('#country').val();
            alert(country);

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" >
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<button id="create-account">click</button>
```

Comment: you skipped onchange=stateChange" I still need that

Comment: You havent provided it in the code above. Thats why i had to skip it.

Comment: Did my solution above answer your question or is there something more to it?

Comment: I edited my answer. the problem was that your country variable doesnt exist outside the click function. So declare it at the top of your js file. Check out my edited answer